# Time Dependant Workflows and transactions

Tags: time-dependent-workflow, transaction

The environment setup is as follows:
1) there is a workflow triggered by some criteria which has a time dependent action which will update a field on the object.
2) With apex-code I update a List of 10 of such objects so that the criteria will fire for all of them

When the time countdown expires, will there be 10 different transactions or will there be 1 transaction with the 10 objects?

Comment: Pretty sure it would be 10 separate transactions, but I'm sure someone will chime in with more definitive knowledge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming they are first up in the queue, they will be one transaction. I have verified this by doing exactly that: I configured a Time-Based Workflow Rule with a field update, then created 10 records at once using execute anonymous. Keep in mind, however, that if you exceed the 50/hour limit for Time Based Workflow rules, or if other records were also inserted/updated before or after those records, they may very well end up in separate transactions. However, please note that this may change at any given release, because it is not specifically documented to have this behavior.